# AutoComplete Per Word C#

Tags: c#, combobox, autocomplete

I'm working on a ComboBoxEdit and I'm trying to implement a dropdown list for autocpmlete per word(see attached gif). Like in visual studio, each word have its drop down list (the same autocomplete source for all the words) and the drop down should move along with the text each time the user type/erase a character. The autocomplete implemented is only for all the text in the ComboBoxEdit and that's it.

[image]

Comment: Look into Prefix trees. Or search indexes if you want fuzzy search etc.

Comment: I doubt that you can tweak the built-in ac to do what you want; so you will have to roll your own.